# DIV auto refresh

Tags: php, ajax, html

I try to refresh div every 5 sec but it doesn't work, I have 3 files.

index.php that contains:

```
     <html>
        <head>  

            <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.3.2.js" ></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/javascript.js" ></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                setInterval ("newmsg()", 5000);
                setInterval ("newpause()", 5000);
                }); 
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="msgs">
                <?php echo date("H:i:s");  ?>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Then I have javascript.js that contains

```
        function GetXmlHttpObject() {
        var xmlHttp = null;
        try {
             xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
             }
        catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
         }
         return xmlHttp;
    }

    function newmsg(){
        var request = GetXmlHttpObject();
        request.open("get", "msgsprint.php", true);
        request.send(null);
        request.onreadystatechange = function response() {
            if (request.readyState === 4) {
                if(request.responseText != "false"){
                    $('#msgs').html(request.responseText);
                }
            }
        }   

    }

    function newpause(){
        var request = GetXmlHttpObject();
        request.open("get", "newpauseprint.php", true);
        request.send(null);
        request.onreadystatechange = function response() {
            if (request.readyState === 4) {
                if(request.responseText != "false"){
                    $('#newpauselist').html(request.responseText);
                }
            }
        }   

    }
```

and i have msgsprint.php that contains

```
<?php
    echo 'ivan'; 
?>
```

Could anybody please tell me what i did wrong.

Comment: What doesn't work? What have you tried? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Just FYI, when using Ajax calls, you should avoid using `setInterval`. Given that your Ajax request takes more than five seconds, your calls will start to stack up. Use `setTimeout` instead, and set a new timeout of five seconds when the Ajax-call completes. That way you can be sure they won't stack.

Comment: thx, no error, just it doesn't refresh the div.

Comment: Well two points (although I'm not sure if either will actually break it) `request.onreadystatechange` should be declared *before* calling `request.send()` and you should pass the function itself to `setInterval()` instead of a string - so do `setInterval(newmsg, 5000);` instead. @ChristoferEliasson makes a very valid point about avoiding the use of `setInterval()` for an ajax call, you should use `setTimeout` in your `onreadystatechange` handler. I'm guessing that your problem is that the server is returning `"false"` - you should add an `else` block to handle this.

Comment: Oh wait hang on I know what the problem is, it's a syntax error: change both instances of `request.onreadystatechange = function response() {` to `request.onreadystatechange = function() {` (remove the word `response`). The fact that you have not seen an error message about this means that you haven't been using the developer console in your browser, which you can get to by pressing the F12 key on your keyboard.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much @ DaveRandom, it worked, I dont konw how i didn't noticet that, (even more i dont know how word response got there).
Thank you all for advices

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong in your code, maybe you are not getting a valid answer from `msgsprint.php`.

Here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DppBp/1/) based on your code that is working fine

I advise you to:
- you test the request status for an error.
- you use `setTimeout` to plan the next call to `newmsgs`

That's what i did in the demo.